# Question about a continuous function such that $f(x^2)=f(x)$.

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Let $f:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that $f(x^{2})=f(x)$, $\forall x\in [0,1]$.

Prove that $f(x^{2n})=f(x)$, $\forall x\in [0,1], \ \ n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Honestly, I don't know how to proceed. I though about induction but I don't know how it could work. It's clear that

$$f(x^{2n})=f((x^{n})^{2})=f(x^{n})$$

But that $n$ could be an even number or an odd number and I don't know how to treat these cases.

I would like an advice for the demonstration, thanks before.

Comment: Hint: call $x^2=t$, then $f(x^4)=f(t^2)=f(t)=f(x^2)=f(x)$. So $f(x^4)=f(x)$.

Comment: It seems that this work only if n=2^t, for example if n=3 your metod doesn't work

Comment: It is supposed to be a hint and as @sera has already answered it you are supposed to use the continuity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that $f(x)=f(x^2)=f(x^4)=f(x^8)= \cdots = f(x^{2^n})$ for all $x \in [0,1]$.

If $0\leq x<1$, then $\lim_{n \to \infty}x^{2^n}=0$. Thus $f(x)=\lim_{n \to \infty}f(x)=\lim_{n \to \infty}f(x^{2^n})=f(0)$ by continuity.

Moreover $f(1)=\lim_{x \to 1}f(x)=\lim_{x \to 1} f(0)=f(0)$. Hence $f$ is a constant function.

Comment: But f(x^(2^n)) is different from f(x^2n)

Comment: Yes, but what I proved is that $f(t_1)=f(t_2)$ holds for any $t_1, t_2 \in [0,1]$. In particular, $f(x^{2n})$ is same to $f(x)$.

Comment: Right, I get it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Take $x\in [0,1)$. You get $f(x)=f(x^2)=f(x^4)...$. The limit of $x^{2^n}$ as $n$ tends to $\infty$ is $0$. By continuity $f(x)=f(0)$. So again by continuity $f$ is constant everywhere on the close interval. This implies $f(x^{2n})=f(x)$.